# Attribute like InheritedExport in Constructor in MEF

Tags: .net, dependencies, mef, composition

I am developing an open ended application and I am new to MEF. I need to hide MEF totally from derived classes. So here is my scenerio.

I have a BaseAssembly

```
public class ListContainer
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IBase))]
    public List<IBase> MyObjects { get; set; }

    public void AssembleDriverComponents()
{
     .... Some code to create catalogue..
     //Crete the composition container
        var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

        // Composable parts are created here i.e. the Import and Export components assembles here
        container.ComposeParts(this);
}
}

 [InheritedExport(typeof(IBase))]
public abstract class Base : IBase
{
    private IInfoBase infoBase;

    //This is something which I want to do. If I have a derived class from Base. 
      Then It does not need to use ImportingConstructor.
    [ImportingConstructor()]
    public Base(InfoBase nfoBase)
    {
        this.infoBase = infoBase;
    }
}

[InheritedExport(typeof(IInfoBase))]
public interface IInfoBase
{
    string Category { get; set; }
}


public class InfoBase : IInfoBase
{

    public string Category
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Other assemblies will refer to base assembly.

ReferenceAssembly will have

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(BaseInfo info)
        : base(info)
    {
        info.Category = "CategoryA";
    }
}
```

In this case MEF is not creating the object for derived one.

In summary, I need something like InheritedExport for ImportingConstructor also.

Comment: I remember coming across this same nuance. I think it comes down to 2 options: A: import `BaseInfo` as a member into `Base` and set `Category` after getting the import. B: use ImportingConstructor

Comment: this is my scenario, unfortunately I cant change this.

Comment: have you tried: in `Base` class, import `IInfoBase infoBase` as a property (not through constructor) and make it `protected` to allow access to derived classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using MEF2. MEF2 introduces the [Convention-Based Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925579.aspx) which can replace or complement the "Attributed Programming Model".

For the interface `IBase`:

```
public interface IBase { }
```

The abstract base class `Base`:

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(IBase))]
public abstract class Base : IBase
{
    private IInfoBase infoBase;

    //No ImportingConstructorAttribute. This will be set with conventions.
    public Base(IInfoBase infoBase)
    {
        this.infoBase = infoBase;
    }
}
```

A couple of `Base` implementations:

```
public class Derived : Base
{        
    public Derived(IInfoBase info)
        : base(info)
    {
        info.Category = "CategoryA";
    }
}

public class AnotherDerived : Base
{
    public AnotherDerived(IInfoBase info)
        : base(info)
    {
        info.Category = "CategoryB";
    }
}
```

The info interface is unchanged:

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(IInfoBase))]    
public interface IInfoBase
{
    string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Added the PartCreationPolicyAttribute so that the exported parts are not shared between the implementations of Base. This doesn't matter though.

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class InfoBase : IInfoBase
{
    public string Category
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And finally the `ListContainer`:

```
public class ListContainer
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IBase))]
    public List<IBase> MyObjects { get; set; }

    public void AssembleDriverComponents()
    {
        var regBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();
        //SelectConstructor is the equivalent of the ImportingConstructorAttribute.
        //Note that my approach here is very crude. Simply use the first constructor.
        regBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<Base>().SelectConstructor(ctors => ctors.First());

        //Only an AssemblyCatalog for this example. Note that the registration 
        //builder is used here.
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), regBuilder);
        //Crete the composition container
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        // Composable parts are created here i.e. the Import and Export components assembles here
        container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(this.MyObjects.Count == 2);
    }
}
```

More info on MEF Conventions:
[MEF 2 article series](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2013/01/06/mef-2-0-toc.aspx) and [Getting started with convention-based part registration in MEF 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/01/getting-started-with-convention-based-part-registration-in-mef-version-2.aspx)